# Ionic2: How do you select which input to focus when you come to the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic2, angular2-directives

When I show the login form it focuses on the password field instead of the email field. I tried a few different solutions to get to focus on the email field but both of them go out of the page. One is the "autofocus" directive which is built into ionic. I also found the "focuser" directive here: https://blog.thecodecampus.de/ionic-2-set-focus-input-element/

Here I click Email / Password to open the form to collect email and password. When the form opens focus is on password. I tried all combinations of adding focuser and autofocus to directives to email and it works but creates an unprofessional jerky UX; not ready for primetime.

HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <br>
  <h1 class="newheadertwo">Sign in or sign up.</h1>
  <p class="p2">Use Facebook or your email and password to get started.</p>
  <br><br>
      <ion-list no-lines *ngIf="!formActive">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <button class="fb-button" (click)="FBLogin()">Facebook Connect</button>
            <br>
            <button class="signup-button" (click)="showForm()">Email / Password</button>
            <br>
            <a (click)="password-retrieve" (click)="forgotPassword()">Forget your password?</a>
            <br>
            <button *ngIf="person" class="login-button-two" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-list>

    <form (ngSubmit)="signUpLogin()" *ngIf="formActive">
      <ion-list class="clearbackground">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating class="input-label">Email Address</ion-label>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email" required="required" type="email" maxlength="200" name="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <br>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating class="input-label">Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" required="required" type="password" maxlength="200" name="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <br>
        <p class="p3">By joining, you agree to the CashPass <a (click)="terms()">Terms</a> and <a (click)="privacy()">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
      </ion-list>
      <button type="submit" class="signup-button">Sign in  /  Join now</button>
    </form>
   <br>
  <ion-row *ngIf="formActive">
    <ion-col>
      <a (click)="password-retrieve" (click)="forgotPassword()">Forget your password?</a>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove all the code that you have written for the autofocus to work. Since, I do not have access to all of the code, cannot help there.
Also, if possible, try this on a new page first and then try to integrate it in your required login page.

In .html, where the input is present : Add an id to the tag.

```
<ion-input id="input" ....></ion-input>
```

In .ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    var input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input');
    console.log("Input :",input);
    input.focus();
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks for the feedback on this but I get input as null. I'm unclear as to what you mean re: "remove all the code that you have written for the autofocus to work. Still working through so if you can add some clarity it'd be appreciated otherwise I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: Removing all the code that you tried before for autofocus to work. If you still not get it, just try doing this on another page first. Also, did you add `id="input"` in <ion-input> tag?

Comment: Also, I just observed you have the `formActive` flag getting checked in `ngIf` of the form. Where are you setting it to true? This can also affect the autofocus thing. I guess you are setting it true after click on `Show Form` button. In that case move this code of `ngAfterViewInit()` in the method `showForm()` after you set `formActive` to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this Angular way by using Ionic view lifecycle hooks, see this example:

in the `.html` page add angular id to the specific element like this `#my_input`

```
<ion-input #my_input [(ngModel)]="email" required="required" type="email" maxlength="200" name="email"></ion-input>
```

in the `.ts` file

```
@Component(...)
export class Page {
  // ion-input is just a component implemented in ionic, so you can get its object using @ViewChild decorator 
  @ViewChild('my_input') myInput: any;

  constructor(...){}

  // this hook is called when the page/component is ready and displayed
  // you can use also angular hooks (ngOnInit, ...) and you can put it in the constructor
  ionViewDidEnter(){
      // use setTimeout to make sure that the page is rendered and to avoid webView lag in android
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.myInput.setFocus();
      }, 300);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but when I add the code you described I keep getting "Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined". The login page is a modal, could that be an issue? I show the form using *ngIf so perhaps I could call focus when I show the form? Is there a way to do this?